# How to search for a string in complex fields in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I want to search for a string in complex fields.

Let's say entity object is

```
{
    _id: "12312",
    name: {
        "en": "English name",
        "br": "brasilian name
}
```

And when I make a search, I want to search in all fields of name.

So

```
db.getCollection('entities').find({"name": /sil/i});
db.getCollection('entities').find({"name": /gl/i});
```

should give me this document. How can I do that?

Comment: Do you really need the regex or are you generally searching on words? Case insensitive matches are not ideal for a database, and nor is matching on anything other than from the beginning of the string. If you really need the regex you either use `$or` and name all the keys or write JavaScript expression with `$where`. And JavaScript expressions are just as bad as the un-anchored regex. Both require a full collection scan.

Comment: I will use it with ui-select so it will do a lot of requests. The problem with $where is, we cannot use parameter inside $where, I guess?

Comment: if your intention is for "autocomplete" then it's not much of an "experience enhancement" if it's going to run dog slow. So there are a few things I think you need to consider. 1. Rule out JavaScript and aggregation brute force with entire collection scans. 2. Possible consider storing in array structure like `[{ "lang": "en", "text": "English" }, { "lang": "br", "text": "Brazil" }]` since at least queries are shorter 3. If going with regex then store copies of fields in normalized case and always search from "anchor" as typed in.

Comment: There are quite a few things about what you are asking here. You probably should expand on your question and explain your use case. "Austoselect" really does not tell anyone here much. It could be an "address search" which regex is fine, or it could be for something like "Google", where what you really want it "text search". The other thing that is not clear here is **why** you need to search in multiple languages or if you even really need that at all. There are use cases, but your question does not state what yours is.

Comment: Also noting someone has answered already showing an aggregation statement. But I recommend you do not use that approach since what is shown takes again a full collection scan and "three" passes through the collection data as opposed to the horrible "one" pass collection scan of techniques already mentioned. For `.aggregate()` to be on the table here, there would need to be a "boolean comparison operator" version of `$regex` for the aggregation framework so we could have one pipeline stage with `$redact`. That operator does not exist, so that I why I don't even consider it.